# Change currency format based on country select

Tags: c#, asp.net, currency

I have a dropdownlist of all countries. I want to be able to display a certain amount in currency format based on the country selected by user.
Currently I'm just using `amount.ToString("C")` and it just displays the dollar sign. But what the user selects a european country then it should be able to display in Euro format?
Is there any way to achieve this in c# on the dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event perhaps?

Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [Formatting Numeric Data for a Specific Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk.aspx):

```
CultureInfo info;
if (country == "Poland")
{
  info = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
}
else if (country == "England")
{
  info = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
}
else
{
  info = new CultureInfo("en-US");
}
Console.WriteLine((1.23).ToString("c", info));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. But I want it to be dynamic. So suppose user selects "United Kingdom" then currency shall format into pounds. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Thanks. But the case is that there is around 200 countries. How can I make it dynamic for all these countries? Do I have to write if else statement for all countries? Sound tedious..

Comment: Put the culture in the value part of the drop down list. You can try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx to see if you can dynamically generate it all as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal price = 123.45m;
int discount = 50;
Console.WriteLine($"Price: {price:C} (Save {discount:C})");
```

Comment: Please add some description around the code. Code-only answers might be correct but it is difficult to understand for future readers.